# SQLCMD variable in database project object

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd, database-project

In visual studio 2012, I have a database project with the following service broker Route object:

```
CREATE ROUTE [MyRoute]
    WITH
        SERVICE_NAME = '[MyService]',
        ADDRESS = '$(MyServiceTarget)'
```

I have the MyServiceTarget configured as a SQLCMD variable in my build. However, when I build and deploy, the ADDRESS is still simply the string `$(MyServiceTarget)` instead of the value of the `MyServiceTarget` SQLCMD variable. How do I fix this?